# Laravel page not found issue with {id} variable

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I have a search function that gives landmarks as a result. However I am now trying to create a details page to view all the details of the landmark selected. I am using a route with {id} parameter and when I click on the anchor the URL in the browser is correct - e.g localhost/pages/details/5, but the error message on the page is "page not found"

My HTML:

```
  @foreach($locations as $location)
    @foreach($location->landmark as $landmark)
      <div class="landmarkAnchor">
        <a href="{{ url('/pages/details/'.$landmark->id) }}">{{$landmark->name}}</a>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/details/{id}', 'SearchController@detailsget');
```

My controller:

```
  public function index(Request $request){
    $landmarks = $request->input('location');
      $locations = Location::whereHas('landmark', function($query) use ($landmarks) {
          $query->where('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%');
      })->get();

    return view('pages.search', compact('locations'));
  }

  public function detailsget($id){
    $landmarks = Landmark::find($id);
    return view('pages.details')->with('landmark', $landmarks);
  }
```

Comment: Your redirect url is `/pages/details/` but the router you define is  `Route::get('/details/{id}', 'SearchController@detailsget');`

Comment: What is your URL? `/pages/details/id` or `/details/id` ?

Comment: /pages/details/id @Saurabh

Comment: @Horcrux, but in your route the URL is is not correct. Please check

Comment: Okay fixed it thanks but now it says new error, Missing required parameters for [Route: details] [URI: details/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\locationsearch\resources\views\pages\details.blade.php), please please help, this needs to be done in 3 hours and I already worked through the night and can't think straight anymore

Comment: @Horcrux, I have added an answer to your above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make your route like this:

```
Route::get('/pages/details/{id}', [
    'as' => 'detailpage',
    'uses' => 'SearchController@detailsget',
]);
```

And your Hyperlinks like this:

```
 <a href="{{ route('detailpage', $landmark->id) }}"> {{$landmark->name}}</a>
```

This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it but it did not work :( error Route [details] not defined

Comment: The route is not named **`details`**, the name is **`detailpage `**.  Did you call the url using **`{{ route('detailpage', $landmark->id) }}`**?

Comment: @Horcrux, did you use the exact code provided above?